# Header not showing up on pages other than main page

Tags: html, css

So, I have a header on the main page of my site. It's perfectly aligned and everything's good, but, when I go to any other page, the header disappears. I've tried it with and without position:fixed, but it still disappears. The space where it should be is still there, but the header itself is invisible, I guess.

I have another div that stays between pages, so I don't know what could possibly be the issue. I've compared the two CSS codes, but the only differences are positions, colors, sizes, etc.

This is the CSS for the header:

```
.bar {
    margin-top:-810px;
    margin-left:300px;
    width:1075px;
    height:60px;
    background-color:#b0b0b0;
    font-size:16px;
    color:#e7e55a;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:60px;
    font-family: 'Coming Soon', cursive;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:1;
}
```

And this is the CSS of the other div that stays in place:

```
#tra img {
    width: 225px;
    height: auto;
    margin-top:60px;
    margin-right:0px;
    transform:rotate(-55deg);
    z-index:1;
}
```

Since the second div is an image, I guess that could be why it stays in place, but I'm really not the best at coding, so any help is appreciated.

Also, I've tried the code without z-index, but it still didn't work.

Comment: Can we see some HTML perhaps? Have you included the header HTML onto the other files?

Comment: I think your posittion:fixed and margins are causing the problem...add your markup

Comment: @k97513 Here's the HTML for the header: 
<div class="bar">
Title
</div>

It's not within any other divs, either.

Comment: @Geeky In what way? I'm not sure how the margins would effect it because the margins are the same for every page. And I've tried it without position:fixed. Still didn't work.

Comment: @AlexM. Please edit your post instead of using comments. Click the "edit" link under your post.

Comment: Can you post the actual html for the areas of concern on the post?

Comment: make `z-index: 100;` for `.bar`

Comment: @k97513 That  the area of concern. It disappears on every page except for the main page.

Comment: @Banzay I've already tried z-index. Doesn't work.

I've also changed the margins and it didn't work. It just moved the header on the main page, but still didn't show up on other pages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you using position fixed use top, left, bottom and right to position your elements. Don't use margin.

```css
.bar {
    top: 0;
    left: 300px;
  
    width:1075px;
    height:60px;
    background-color:#b0b0b0;
    font-size:16px;
    color:#e7e55a;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:60px;
    font-family: 'Coming Soon', cursive;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="bar"></div>
```

Comment: That was the single simplest thing I've ever done, wow. Thanks so much!